# Stack program always popping 0

Tags: c++, stack

This is my stack program implementation by using liked list

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct SNode
    {
        int data;
        struct SNode* next;
    };
    void push(struct SNode** top,int x)
    {
        struct SNode* temp=(struct SNode*)malloc(sizeof(SNode));
        {
            struct SNode* holder=*top;
            temp->data=x;
            temp->next=(holder);
            holder=temp;
            printf("%d was Pushed",x);
        }
    }
```

I dont get this..i think there is spme problem here...

```
void pop(struct SNode** top)
{
    struct SNode* temp;
    struct SNode* holder=*top;
    int x1;
    if(holder==NULL)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty ");
    }

    temp=holder;
    x1=holder->data;
    holder=holder->next;
    printf("%d was popped  from the stack",x1);
    free(temp);
}
```

over here too It always shows 0 at the top of the stack

```
void peek(struct SNode* top)
{
    printf("%d is at the top of the stack",top);
}
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int x,c,c1;
    jump:
```

This is my label

```
 printf("Do you want to Push/Pop/Peek an element ??\n");
            printf("1)Push\t2)Pop\t3)Peek\n");
            scanf("%d",&c);
            struct SNode* top=NULL;
```

switch case

```
switch(c)
                {
```

push

```
case 1:


    {
                                printf("Enter Element :");
                                scanf("%d",&x);
                                push(&top,x);
                                printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                                scanf("%d",&c1);
                                if(c1==1)
                                {
                                    goto jump;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    printf("GGWP....");
                                }
                            break;

                            }
```

pop

```
case 2:
                        {
                            pop(&top);
                            printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                            scanf("%d",&c1);
                            if(c1==1)
                            {
                                goto jump;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("GGWP....");
                            }
                            break;

                        }
```

Top of the stack

```
            case 3:
            {
                peek(top);
                printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                scanf("%d",&c1);
                if(c1==1)
                {
                    goto jump;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("GGWP....");
                }
                break;

            }
                    default:
                    {
                        printf("Enter the correct option ...");
                        goto jump;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                getch();
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: And don't use `goto` without a serious reasoning please!

Comment: To begin with, your "pop()" is not actually popping (there is no assignment to the "*top"). Thus, it prints the top element and frees it, but the "top" remains pointing to that dangling memory.

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: why *void main()*?

Comment: Then what should I have....??@the techel

Comment: did you try to compile this with a C++ version?  If so then which?  Did it compile?  What were the compile/run-time errors that the compiler kicked out?

Comment: This is clearly C code, but you are (most likely) running it through a C++ compiler, otherwise the line `struct SNode* temp=(struct SNode*)malloc(sizeof(SNode));` wouldn't compile. And `void main()` is a non-standard declaration, it should be `int main(void)` in C or `int main()` in C++

Answer (score 0):

This code works... I made some blunders

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct SNode
{
    int data;
    struct SNode* next;
};
void push(struct SNode** top,int x)
{
    struct SNode* temp=(struct SNode*)malloc(sizeof(SNode));
    {
```

Holder will not maintain the structure for that you will have to return its value and capture it in void main()
            //struct SNode* holder=*top;

```
temp->data=x;
            temp->next=(*top);
            *top=temp;
            printf("%d was Pushed",temp->data);
        }
    }
    void pop(struct SNode** top)
    {
        struct SNode* temp;
        int x1;
        if(*top==NULL)
        {
            printf("Stack is empty ");
        }
        //printf("%d",*top->data);
        temp=*top;
        x1=(*top)->data;
        *top=(*top)->next;
        printf("%d was popped  from the stack",x1);
        free(temp);
    }
    void peek(struct SNode* top)
    {
        printf("%d is at the top os the stack",top->data);
    }
    void main()
    {
        clrscr();
        int x,c,c1;
        int i;
        struct SNode* top=NULL;
        int counter=0;
        jump:
        printf("Do you want to Push/Pop/Peek/Display an element ??\n");
        printf("1)Push\t2)Pop\t3)Peek\t4)Display\n");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Enter Element :");
                scanf("%d",&x);
                push(&top,x);
                counter++;
                printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                scanf("%d",&c1);
                if(c1==1)
                {
                    goto jump;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("GGWP....");
                }
            break;

            }
            case 2:
            {
                pop(&top);
                counter--;
                printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                scanf("%d",&c1);
                if(c1==1)
                {
                    goto jump;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("GGWP....");
                }
                break;

            }
            case 3:
            {
                peek(top);
                printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                scanf("%d",&c1);
                if(c1==1)
                {
                    goto jump;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("GGWP....");
                }
                break;

            }
            case 4:
            {
                for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
                {
                    int x2;
                    x2=(top)->data;
                    printf("%d ->",x2);
                    top=(top)->next;

                }
                printf("\nDo you want to continue :1)Yes 2)No\n");
                scanf("%d",&c1);
                if(c1==1)
                {
                    goto jump;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("GGWP....");
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf("Enter the correct option ...");
                goto jump;
                break;

            }
        }
        getch();
    }
```